# Recommended Windsor architecture for non-trivial project dependencies

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

We have around 20 self-contained projects in our solution. Each project is a stand-alone component and has its own Windsor installer. With this structure, we are finding our Windsor installers becoming large, unmanageable and brittle.

In our solution, some over-arching projects depend on a subset of other smaller projects, and some projects depend on another.

A diagram of the structure would be similar to this, where arrows indicate dependencies:

[image]

Don't dwell on the naming of each item in the diagram. They're just different projects which are separated for manageability and reuse concerns.

The two approaches I can see for the Windor installation is:

1. Each component installs its dependencies. In this example, the API's installer installs Component A and Component B. Likewise, Component A's installer installs Module A and Module B, and Component B's installer installs module B and Module C. This is my preferred solution as it provides neat encapsulation.
2. The top-level project installs all dependencies in the solution. In this example, the API's installer installs both Component A and B, and all three modules.

The down-side of the first approach is that each installer which *may* be installed more than once needs to use `Component.For<X>.OnlyNewServices()` for each registration. This is verbose and easy to forget and really needs to be applied to every single registration to allow for application growth and component reuse.

The down-side of the second approach is that the projects end up requiring knowledge of components which they have no concern knowing about, and encapsulation is broken.

Questions:

1. Is there a way in Windsor to set *default* behaviour so components may be registered multiple times?
2. Alternatively, is there some other recommended Windsor architecture for non-trivial dependencies (for example, sub-containers)?

Comment: For the person who voted to close this question as being too broad, the tl;dr version is "what is the recommended approach to developing modules in Windsor without registration collisions."

Comment: Applications should have a composition root; not projects: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/

Comment: I'm referring to Visual Studio projects/assemblies. Each 'module' and 'component' in my example is a c# class library. I'm not sure how your link is related. I am very reluctant to require the application's entry point (the API project) to have a monolithic Windsor installer which installs not only its dependancies, but the dependancies of those dependancies, and so on. I don't know if that's what Mark is suggesting, but it seems impractical for a project of any size, if so.

Comment: Although I can understand, to a point. Introducing Windsor installers into libraries creates multiple dependencies on Windsor. However, I'm comfortable with this trade-off. Windsor is a given in our organisation, we're not publishing libraries for external consumption, and I would far prefer to see principles of abstraction used where possible when creating the object graph. A developer on the API project only needs to know that it depends on Component A and Component B. Anything else is just noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this elegantly by using Windsor's built in assembly scanning. Each project now only installs the components defined in the project, doesn't explicitly install any other installers and doesn't eagerly resolve components from other assemblies.

The API project contains:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Install(FromAssembly.InThisApplication());
```

Part of the reason for our unmanageable installers is that some installers were doing early resolution of dependent components. This is an anti-pattern and enforces installer order. Removing this need makes application-wide installation trivial.